# ExtJs Panel grid columns disappear after data loaded

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I'm loading data into a Panel Grid using `loadData` function. In the browser, I see the load mask, and the data for the fraction of a second, and then all the columns disappear. When I refresh the browser a couple of times, sometimes I see the columns, but sometimes I don't. My data is in the following format:

```
data  = [
    { name: 'ExtJs'},
    { name: 'ExtJs'},
    { name: 'ExtJs'}
]
```

Any ideas why the grid columns disappear?

Comment: Post your code please, the data is not enough to advise anything helpful.

Comment: Post the grid columns and your model.

Comment: It works when I turn off autoload in the store.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do a refresh after render to force the columns to show first time

```
afterrender: function(grid){
grid.getView().refresh();
}
```